# Watch a BitCoin account for incoming payments

Tags: wallet, address, smartcontracts, wallet-notify

I want to watch a set of BitCoin addresses and be notified (preferably by email) when they receive a payment.

I prefer me not to write my own software for this and not to install it on my own server, but programming suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You need a server which indexes by address. Libbitcoin-server provides this index. All tx’s to or from an address of interest will trigger a notification to your subscribing client.

https://github.com/libbitcoin/libbitcoin-server/wiki

Of course you can always build your own address index.

Answer (score 1):

Without installing software on your own servers, the only way to accomplish this is with 3rd Party services. Some offer Email notification of payments via email.

blockcypher.com is an example of this.